# Implementing cache using infinispan doesn't work. How to fix?

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, infinispan

I am implementing cache in a part of my spring-boot project using Infinipsan.

Here's what I did:
1. I added *@EnableCaching* in spring boot initializer file in project1.
2. Updated *application.properties* and *infinispan.xml* accordingly and created a dummy weather method in project1 to check caching and it worked just fine.
3. Then coming to my real implementation. Initially, the request hits the controller of project1 here

```java
    @GetMapping("stream")
    public String stream() {
        return "stream";
    }
```

4. In project1, in *stream.jsp*, a *stream.js* is loaded which makes a request to the controller with url 'frame' in a different project(call it project2) (imported to project1 in its pom.xml) with certain data:

```java
    @Inject
    @Named("faceRecognition")
    private FaceRecognition faceRecognition;

    @RequestMapping("/frame")
    public Object recognize(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> payload) {
        return faceRecognition.recognizeFace(payload);
    }
```

5. Now coming to faceRecognition class, here it is:

```java
    @Named("faceRecognition")
    public class FaceRecognition {

    //implementing the method
    @Cacheable(value="testCache", id="#empIdArr")
    public ResponseVO elasticSearchDataRet(String empIdArr) {
        ResponseVO responseVO = new ResponseVO();
        responseVO.setIndex(empIdArr);
        responseVO.setType("None");
        responseVO.setStatus("Success");
        System.out.println("Not cached yet");
        return responseVO;
    }

    public String recognizeFace(Map<String, Object> payload) {
        ...After doing few things...

        //calling the method. Here empIdArr = [2000]
        elasticSearchDataRet(empIdArr[0]);

        ...Do some stuff....
    }
    }
```

**Result**: On checking in *localhost:3000/metrics*, 'cache.testCache.size' (testCache is name of my cache) is 0 and it prints "Not cached yet" every time a request is made, i.e. caching isn't working.

What's wrong with the code?

**Edit:** When I change faceRecognition class to as shown below(changing the position of @Cacheable), in *localhost:3000/metrics*, 'cache.testCache.size' starts incrementing, though it still prints "Not cached yet" every time a request is made:

```java
    @Named("faceRecognition")
    @Cacheable(value="testCache", id="#empIdArr")
    public class FaceRecognition {

    //implementing the method
    public ResponseVO elasticSearchDataRet(String empIdArr) {
        ResponseVO responseVO = new ResponseVO();
        responseVO.setIndex(empIdArr);
        responseVO.setType("None");
        responseVO.setStatus("Success");
        System.out.println("Not cached yet");
        return responseVO;
    }

    public String recognizeFace(Map<String, Object> payload) {
        ...After doing few things...

        //calling the method. Here empIdArr = [2000]
        elasticSearchDataRet(empIdArr[0]);

        ...Do some stuff....
    }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using invalidation mode by any chance?

Comment: No, I am not using invalidation mode in my project.

Comment: Which version of spring-boot are you using? Are you using spring implementation or spring-boot starter? https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-spring-boot

Comment: I am not using Infinispan Spring Boot Starter in the project. It is version 1.5.4 of spring-boot. I've added further information in the question. Please look at it.

Comment: Could you try putting ```@CacheConfig(cacheNames ="testCache" )``` at the class level, and put ```@Cacheable``` in the method, please? I would also recommend to use the infinispan-spring-boot starter (version 1.5.x and 2.1.x supported). The integration offers much more capabilities and the infinispan team actively supports that integration. Thanks!

Comment: Karesti, I did what you said, but it still didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Which version of infinispan are you using?

Comment: The version of infinispan is "8.2.6.Final".

Comment: Did you try upgrading spring-boot version and using the infinispan-spring-boot starter? We support spring-boot starter on version 1.5.17 now with Infinispan 9.4.x. The integration you are using has been developed by the spring-boot team and your project could benefit a lot from upgrading to the latest 1.5.x version. Along with the infinispan version that it supports. If you have a reproducer of the problem that I may grab a look at, I would be more than happy to help. I can't help any further without a reproducer. Thanks!